# ASP.net + JS multiple textboxes character counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I tried to create jquery script that will count number of characters in my multiline textboxes. When i do it for single one, everything is OK. But i have a lot of multiline textboxes. Can i make my sript more robust so i don't have to set every textbox manually? I made it for single textboxes:

Here my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox585" runat="server" Width="99%" TextMode="MultiLine"  ToolTip = "blabla"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <div id="TextBox585_feedback" style="text-align: right">
```

script attached to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var text_max = 1000;
        function ValidateTextBoxLen(textBox, textBoxFeedBack) {
            var text_length = textBox.val().length;
            var remaining = text_max - text_length;
            if (remaining < 0) {
                textBoxFeedBack.html('Will be cut ' + (0 - remaining) + ' characters.');
            } else {
                textBoxFeedBack.html('Remaining characters: ' + remaining);
            }
        }
     $('#MainContent_TextBox585').keyup(function () { ValidateTextBoxLen($('#MainContent_TextBox585'), $('#TextBox585_feedback')); });


    });
    </script>
```

and VB.net code to set max characters to multiline textbox:

```
TextBox585.Attributes.Add("maxlength", "1000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your script to look at a class rule assigned to each textbox, as you're currently referring to the ID's of the textboxes, which is always unique per textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox585" runat="server" {class="validatable_textbox"} Width="99%" TextMode="MultiLine"  ToolTip = "blabla"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then the script can be modified to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var text_max = 1000;
        function ValidateTextBoxLen(textBox, textBoxFeedBack) {
            var text_length = textBox.val().length;
            var remaining = text_max - text_length;
            if (remaining < 0) {
                textBoxFeedBack.html('Will be cut ' + (0 - remaining) + ' characters.');
            } else {
                textBoxFeedBack.html('Remaining characters: ' + remaining);
            }
        }
     $('#MainContent_TextBox585').keyup(function () { ValidateTextBoxLen($('.validatable_textbox')); });


    });
```

The change is here:

```
$('#MainContent_TextBox585').keyup(function () { ValidateTextBoxLen($('.validatable_textbox')); });
```

Comment: Sounds good but how i will tell script to set feedback to right div?

Comment: One way, but not limited to, is this: https://jsfiddle.net/bk041njz/15/ you just need to make it work for your scenario.